# Resolving a type with generic interface subtype

Tags: c#, .net, generics

Can anyone please tell me why this evalution returns false:

```
using System;
                    
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var a = new Type();
        Console.WriteLine(a is IType<ISubType>); //false
    }
}

public class Type : IType<SubType>
{
}
public interface IType<T>
{
}
    
public class SubType : ISubType
{
}
public interface ISubType
{
}
```

[.NET Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/nU039m)

Comment: [Covariance and Contravariance (C#)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/covariance-contravariance/) `IType<SubType>` and `IType<ISubType>` are two completely different things.

Comment: In general, an `ICollection<Giraffe>` would not be an `ICollection<IAnimal>`, even if a `Giraffe` is an `IAnimal`, since the former does not accept `Snake`s while the latter does.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `SubType` has its own behaviour independent of `ISubType`. As `Type` has some relation to `SubType`, it can count on this independent behaviour of `SubType`.

For example,

```
public class SubType : ISubType
{
    public void Print()
    {
        System.Console.WriteLine("Hello!");
    }
}

var test1 = new List<SubType>
{
    new SubType()
};
test1.First().Print(); //OK

var test2 = new List<ISubType>
{
    new SubType()
};
test2.First().Print(); //Error CS1061: 'ISubType' does not contain a definition for 'Print' and no accessible extension method 'Print' …
```

Answer (score 1):

@Jeroen Mostert has a very good comment on the question. Continuing with that reasoning, if you want the evaluation to return `true`. Please declare your interface like this:

```
public interface IType<out T>
{

}
```

You could use `ICollection<Animal>` as `ICollection<Giraffe>` to get Giraffes out of a collection of Animals

https://dotnetfiddle.net/bnUG1S